# Is it possible to add endianness and bit-depth conversion in the linux soundcard / ASoC drivers?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, alsa

As in the title, is it possible to add some transfer function to the ASoC soundcard or CODEC driver, that would do the endianness and bit-depth conversion? After the initial research it seems that such function could be implemented in `snd_soc_component_driver.read` and `snd_soc_component_driver.write`.

```c
struct snd_soc_component_driver {
    const char *name;
    /* a lot of more functions here */
    unsigned int (*read)(struct snd_soc_component *component,
                 unsigned int reg);
    int (*write)(struct snd_soc_component *component,
             unsigned int reg, unsigned int val);
    /* and here as well */
}
```

Is it possible to overlay the default read/write functions so that the new functions would only do the conversion and pass the data further?

The `.write` and `.read` definitions are very similarly to `snd_soc_component_write` and `snd_soc_component_read`, are these the default write/read functions attached to the `snd_soc_component_driver`, when no other functions are defined?

```c
/* component IO */
unsigned int snd_soc_component_read(struct snd_soc_component *component,
                      unsigned int reg);
int snd_soc_component_write(struct snd_soc_component *component,
                unsigned int reg, unsigned int val);
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/sound/soc/soc-component.c#L728 I do not see a default, it just uses it.

Comment: In that case, do you think I could put `snd_soc_component_read` into my own `read` function and do the conversion there?

Comment: You need to add a wrapper that does the conversion **and** calls the original function.